# How to index a day's range of rows in a Dataframe, using a datetime.date?

Tags: python, pandas

My multi-indexed data frame is as follows:

```
df.head()
                         Output  
Unit    Timestamp                                               
1   2016-06-01 00:00:00  225894.9
    2016-06-01 01:00:00  225895.9
    2016-06-01 02:00:00  225896.9   
    2016-06-01 03:00:00  225897.9 
    2016-06-01 04:00:00  225898.9 

df.tail()

                         Output 
Unit Timestamp                                               
16  2016-06-30 18:00:00  150543.1        
    2016-06-30 19:00:00  150544.1        
    2016-06-30 21:00:00  150546.1        
    2016-06-30 22:00:00  150547.1     
    2016-06-30 23:00:00  150548.1
```

That is, one month's worth of hourly data for 16 units.

I want to pick out one day's data for a given unit. I have an array of the days that appear in the dataframe,

`days = array([datetime.date(2016, 6, 1), datetime.date(2016, 6, 2),
       datetime.date(2016, 6, 3), datetime.date(2016, 6, 4),...` etc etc

If I do `df.ix[5,'2016-06-10']`, I get exactly what I want, that is the day's for unit 5 that date

```
                       Output
Timestamp
2016-06-10 00:00:00    152364.6
2016-06-10 01:00:00    152365.7
2016-06-10 02:00:00    152366.6
...
2016-06-10 21:00:00    152386.6
2016-06-10 22:00:00    152386.6
2016-06-10 23:00:00    152387.6
```

But the same indexing doesn't seem to work when I have a datetime.date object instead of a string. For example:

`tenth = days[9]` evaulates to `datetime.date(2016, 6, 10)`, so far so good.

However when I do `df.ix[5,tenth]` I get "KeyError: u'no item named 2016-06-10'"

So, the `'2016-06-10'` "does what I mean" and returns all the data on that day. How can I do the same if with a datetime.date?

Comment: can you maybe paste  a small sample of your data, not necessarily enough to include more than one unit? perhaps the results of `df.head(40).to_dict()`

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/38346697/2336654

Comment: Is your index level `Timestamp` really Pandas `DateTimeIndex`? Double check that.

Comment: @piRSquared `type(tenth)` is `datetime.date`. Also I read about `slice` but I think it's in a later pandas version than I have available. Therefore @Karrtik, it is not a DateTimeIndex. That might well help!

Comment: @Kartik - correction, yes the `Timestamp`s are of type `DatetimeIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a string that looks like a datetime to the pandas selector `ix`, it uses it like a condition and returns all elements that satisfy.  In this case, the string you are using evaluates to a day.  Pandas runs `ix` and returns all rows within that day.  When you pass the datetime object, it looks for an exact match.  You don't have one since all your datetimes are non-zero hour times.

Consider:

```
s = pd.Series(range(5), pd.date_range('2016-03-31 01:00:00', periods=5, freq='H'))
s

2016-03-31 01:00:00    0
2016-03-31 02:00:00    1
2016-03-31 03:00:00    2
2016-03-31 04:00:00    3
2016-03-31 05:00:00    4
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

get all elements on `'2016-03-31'`

```
s.ix['2016-03-31']

2016-03-31 01:00:00    0
2016-03-31 02:00:00    1
2016-03-31 03:00:00    2
2016-03-31 04:00:00    3
2016-03-31 05:00:00    4
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

Now assign a datetime

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2016-03-31')

s.ix[date]
```

And...

> ```
> KeyError: Timestamp('2016-03-31 00:00:00')
> ```

If instead we assigned a datetime where we do have an exact match, we should get a result.

```
date2 = pd.to_datetime('2016-03-31 02:00:00')
```

Then

```
s.ix[date2]
```

Returns:

```
1
```

That worked!

To use datetimes and make it look pretty, use a function:

```
d2s = lambda d: d.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
```

Then

```
s.ix[d2s(date)]

2016-03-31 01:00:00    0
2016-03-31 02:00:00    1
2016-03-31 03:00:00    2
2016-03-31 04:00:00    3
2016-03-31 05:00:00    4
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I reckoned something like that must be happening with `ix` processing the string; your solution does work in the sense that it does not give an error but I wanted a whole days' worth of data. I want to take advantage of what `ix` does but using a variable. I did also try `df.ix[5,tenth.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')]` but that doesn't work either and starts to look more that a little silly!

Comment: `d2s(tenth)` gives me `'2016-06-10'` but `df.ix[5,d2s(tenth)]` gives me the same error.

Comment: @djnz0feh fixed, I used wrong format.  I updated post.

Comment: Arrgh! with `d2s = lambda d: d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` it does of course work. Well done. Funny I got that far before posting the question and didn't notice the wrong date format.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest you a different method rather than using ix. Why don't you directly use a range query?

```
df = df[df.index.get_level_values('Unit') == 6 & 
        (df.index.get_level_values('Timestamp') >= tenth & 
        (df.index.get_level_values('Timestamp') <= tenth)]
```

Can you just try whether this is working?

Comment: To use this approach exactly as you say I'd need to maintain an `eleventh` and use it instead of the second `tenth` in suggestion. What does so far seem to work is `df[(df.index.get_level_values('Unit') == 6) & (df.index.get_level_values('Timestamp').date == tenth.date())]`. Note which date is a function and which is a property!